# Load data from the database to mat-table when click Next page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, angular-material, spring-data, angular7

I am using angular 7 with spring boot, and i am use mat-table, i don't want load for example all the data from database in one load, i want to load data just when click on next page in mat-table.
and This image for my mat-table.

[image: mat-table image]

how i  can do that in angular 7 and spring boot together, if anybody have solution please give me it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  `JpaRepository` of `Spring-data-jpa`there is a `Pageable` concept, in your repo implement `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository` (It internally extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`)

You could do something like this,

#### Repo

```java
public class FooRepository extends JpaRepository<FooClass, Long> {
}
```

#### Service

```java
@Service
public class FooService {

  @Autowired
  private FooRepository fooRepo;

  public Page<FooClass> fetchPagedFoo(Integer page, Integer size) {
   return fooRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size)); 
  }
}
```

#### Controller

```java
@RestController
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public ResponseEntity getPagedFoo(
            @RequestParam(value = "pageIndex", defaultValue ="0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "10") Integer size) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fooService.fetchPagedFoo(page, size));
    }
}
```

In above if you pass 0, 10 then first page 10 rows will be returned, `Page` will return total number of data as well with this you could do `Pagination`.

Comment: OK thanks, i will implement this concept